# winforms webbrowser control implementing IAuthenticate navigate fails with Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have an application which displays images and we're moving them to a different server.  On the existing server, they can view as many images as they want and it won't ask them to log in again.  On the new server, it asks them to log in before they can view an image even though the browser control has their credentials. If I take the value of the web browser's absoluteUri property and paste it into IE, it loads the image without asking to log in.

I'm trying to pass the userID and password credentials to the webBrowser control on my form by implementing IAuthenticate, and all the examples I found online are in C#.  In trying to narrow down where the problem is, I've commented out the IAuthenticate implementation because it gets errors before the implementation is called.  Right now I have:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComImport(),
Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IOleObject
    Sub SetClientSite(pClientSite As IOleClientSite)
    Sub GetClientSite(ppClientSite As IOleClientSite)
    Sub SetHostNames(szContainerApp As Object, szContainerObj As Object)
    Sub Close(dwSaveOption As UInteger)
    Sub SetMoniker(dwWhichMoniker As UInteger, pmk As Object)
    Sub GetMoniker(dwAssign As UInteger, dwWhichMoniker As UInteger, ppmk As Object)
    Sub InitFromData(pDataObject As IDataObject, fCreation As Boolean, dwReserved As UInteger)
    Sub GetClipboardData(dwReserved As UInteger, ppDataObject As IDataObject)
    Sub DoVerb(iVerb As UInteger, lpmsg As UInteger, pActiveSite As Object, lindex As UInteger, hwndParent As UInteger, lprcPosRect As UInteger)
    Sub EnumVerbs(ppEnumOleVerb As Object)
    Sub Update()
    Sub IsUpToDate()
    Sub GetUserClassID(pClsid As UInteger)
    Sub GetUserType(dwFormOfType As UInteger, pszUserType As UInteger)
    Sub SetExtent(dwDrawAspect As UInteger, psizel As UInteger)
    Sub GetExtent(dwDrawAspect As UInteger, psizel As UInteger)
    Sub Advise(pAdvSink As Object, pdwConnection As UInteger)
    Sub Unadvise(dwConnection As UInteger)
    Sub EnumAdvise(ppenumAdvise As Object)
    Sub GetMiscStatus(dwAspect As UInteger, pdwStatus As UInteger)
    Sub SetColorScheme(pLogpal As Object)
End Interface

<ComImport(),
Guid("00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IOleClientSite
    Sub SaveObject()
    Sub GetMoniker(ByVal dwAssign As Integer, ByVal dwWhichMoniker As Integer, ByRef ppmk As Object)
    Sub GetContainer(ByRef ppContainer As Object)
    Sub ShowObject()
    Sub OnShowWindow(ByVal fShow As Boolean)
    Sub RequestNewObjectLayout()
End Interface

<ComImport(),
Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IServiceProvider
    <PreserveSig()>
    Sub QueryService(ByRef guidService As Guid, ByRef riid As Guid,
          <Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByRef ppvObject As Object)
End Interface

<ComImport> _
<Guid("79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Public Interface IAuthenticate
    '<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)
Sub Authenticate(phwnd As IntPtr,
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByRef pszUsername As String,
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByRef pszPassword As String)
End Interface

Public Class frmIE
    Implements IOleClientSite
    Implements IServiceProvider

    Public Shared IID_IAuthenticate As New Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")

    Private _user As String
    Private _pwd As String

    Friend WriteOnly Property url(user As String, pwd As String) As System.Uri
        Set(ByVal value As System.Uri)
            Dim oc As IOleObject

            webIE.Navigate("about:blank")       ' iAuthenticate not always called on first run
            oc = DirectCast(webIE.ActiveXInstance, IOleObject)
            ' if I comment the following line out, it loads the image ok and asks for credentials
            oc.SetClientSite(DirectCast(Me, IOleClientSite))   ' instead of trycast, so can see error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

            _user = user
            _pwd = pwd
            webIE.Navigate(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub GetContainer(ByRef ppContainer As Object) Implements IOleClientSite.GetContainer
        ppContainer = Me   ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetMoniker(dwAssign As Integer, dwWhichMoniker As Integer, ByRef ppmk As Object) Implements IOleClientSite.GetMoniker
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0           ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub
    Public Sub OnShowWindow(fShow As Boolean) Implements IOleClientSite.OnShowWindow
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0          ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub
    Public Sub RequestNewObjectLayout() Implements IOleClientSite.RequestNewObjectLayout
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0           ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub
    Public Sub SaveObject() Implements IOleClientSite.SaveObject
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0          ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub
    Public Sub ShowObject() Implements IOleClientSite.ShowObject
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0         ' doesn't reach stop placed here
    End Sub


    Public Sub QueryService(ByRef guidService As System.Guid, ByRef riid As System.Guid,
                             <Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByRef ppvObject As Object) Implements IServiceProvider.QueryService
        If guidService.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate) = 0 AndAlso riid.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate) = 0 Then
            'ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(Me, GetType(IAuthenticate))   ' doesn't reach stop placed here
        Else
            ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero        ' does reach stop placed here, 2x
            ' 1st guid is 4c96be40-915c-11cf-99d3-00aa004ae837 = SID_SToplevelBrowser 
            ' 1st riid is 02ba3b52-0547-11d1-b833-00c04fc9b31f
            ' 2nd guid is SID_SToplevelBrowser
            ' 2nd riid is 6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

but it's giving me an error on the line

```
oc.SetClientSite(DirectCast(Me, IOleClientSite))
```

saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"  Which looks like a generic error that could have many causes.

I'm assuming I've missed some declaration or usage detail, but I can't tell where or if that's even really the problem.

All help appreciated,

-Beth

Answer (score 0):

We ended up passing the navigate method of the webBrowser object a string instead of a new system.uri object, and that fixed it for us.